# Using any() in condition to find value inside tuple, inside list

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, conditional-statements, any

I want to validate if a certain value is present within a tuple inside a list.

Now I wonder why this works:

```
list = [(1,2)] # tuple inside a list
# check if numbers are in tuple
if any(3 in pair for pair in list) or any(4 in pair for pair in list):
    print('Yep, found something')
else:
    print('Nope')
```

```
output: 'Nope'
```

And why this doesn't work:

```
list = [(1,2)] # tuple inside a list
# check if numbers are in tuple
if (3 in pair for pair in list) or (4 in pair for pair in list):
    print('Yep, found something')
else:
    print('Nope')
```

```
output: 'Yep, found something'
```

What are the mechanics at play here? Why doesn't example 2 work?

I clearly misunderstood something, but cannot find out. Can anyone explain please?

Comment: You should look at the value produced by `(3 in pair for pair in l) or (4 in pair for pair in l)`. It's not a boolean. It's a generator object because an expression like `(3 in pair for pair in l)` produces a generator. This will evaluate to `True` in this context.

Comment: Thank you! I also just read the suggested other question and the replies there answer my question.